How can I dynamically generate optional fields with Pydantic when using a deep nested structure?
I'm using Pydantic to create objects in my integration tests, and I'm currently generating required fields automatically with a default_factory. For example:
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from faker import Faker

faker = Faker()

class Foo3(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(default_factory=faker.sentence)
    city: str = None  # city is optional, but it can't be `None`

The problem arises when I have deeply nested models, and I want to generate some optional fields dynamically. For example, I want to be able to generate an object without the optional field city but still have the option to include it when necessary. In complex models with multiple nested objects, this becomes cumbersome.
What would be the best approach to automatically generate required fields while either omitting or including optional fields as needed, without having to manually specify each optional field for deeply nested models?
